# Convert Text to Date/Time Object In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object with these two fields...

```
"start_datetime": "3/9/2016 8:00",
"stop_datetime": "3/18/2016 16:00",
```

How can I tell if the current date/time is between these two?

**16:00 - 4PM**

**08:00 - 8AM**

Comment: `new Date("3/18/2016 16:00")`

Comment: But how would I be able to tell if I am in between these two dates?

Comment: `Date.now() > new Date("3/9/2016 8:00") && Date.now() < new Date("3/18/2016 16:00")`, have fun  @softwareisfun

Answer (score 2):

DateTime objects can be compared with the standard comparison operators to tell if one is before the other.

```
var start = new Date(obj.start_datetime);
var end = new Date(obj.end_datetime);
var now = new Date();

if (now > start && now < end) {
    // current date and time between start and end
} else {
   // current date and time not between start and end
}
```